# how to get the text of radiobuttons from a group of radiobuttons in python

Tags: python

how to get the text of radiobuttons from a group of radiobuttons in python?
I want to print the text of the selected radiobutton. I spent hours trying to program a command that is able to do so, but i failed.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far

Comment: for eg. I tried to use indexes and for every index, i write:print("name of the index"), but it failed. also, i could change the whole program and use buttons instead, but that will require a lot of code unlike radiobuttons which is a minimalistic approach. so now i am wondering if i am wasting time by sticking to radiobuttons and that there isnt a solution